# How to override default argparse error messages

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am using argparse to parse input arguments. One of the required ones are files, but I want to change the error message:

```
x.py: error: the following arguments are required: files
```

to something else. How to do that? I get how you change message if an optional flag is not supplied, but it does not work for mandatory arguments.

I would also like to change this message:

```
usage: x.py [-h] files [files ...]
```

Cheers!

Comment: It might help if you gave the `argparse` code that you do use, and describe what kind of change you want in the error message.  But beyond showing you where, in the code, the message is generated, I probably can't help you much.  As for the usage, you can define your own `usage` string in the parser definition.  It looks like you have defined 'files' as a `nargs='+'` Action.  What's wrong with the default usage?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this question, I think it will get you on the right track.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942165